# understanding random number code in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly

I found here on forum a code to generate a random number between 0 and 9 in Assembly 8086. Here is the code:

```
    RANDSTART:
   MOV AH, 2ch         
   INT 21h       
   mov  ax, dx
   xor  dx, dx
   mov  cx, 10    
   div  cx       
   mov si, dx
   mov variable, si
```

Please, I need you guys to explain me this line:

```
 xor  dx, dx
```

I don't understand why we need to use the xor here.
Hope you guys can help and teach me :)

Comment: Do you know what `div` does?

Comment: `xor dx, dx` just zeroes DX.

Comment: `xor`ing a register with itself is another way of setting it to zero, since any number xor itself is zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot , now i understand , xor dx,dx is equal to mov dx,0?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to zero a register, and the xor method is one of the more common methods.

Answer (score 0):

`xor dx,dx` equals `mov dx,0`.
Its is a logic gate that:

```
1+1=0 
0+0=0 
1+0=1 
0+1=1
```

Basically when you `xor` a number by itself the output is 0.
It is preferred over the `mov` command because it takes less memory.
Hope you understand a little better now.

Comment: There is a slight difference. XOR will alter the FLAGS, MOV doesn't.